# find command in bash script resulting in "No such file or directory" error only for directories?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, find

**UPDATE 2014-03-21**

So I realized I wasn't as efficient as I could be, as all the disks that I needed to "scrub" were under `/media` and named "`disk1`, `disk2`,`disk3`, etc."  Here's the final script:

```
DIRTY_DIR="/media/disk*" 
find $DIRTY_DIR -depth -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf {} \;
find $DIRTY_DIR -depth -type d -name .AppleDB -exec rm -rf {} \;
find $DIRTY_DIR -depth -type d -name .AppleDesktop -exec rm -rf {} \;
find $DIRTY_DIR -type f -name ".*DS_Store" -exec rm -f {} \;
find $DIRTY_DIR -type f -name ".Thumbs.db" -exec rm -f {} \; #  I know, I know, this is a Windows file.
```

Next will probably to just clean up the code even more, and add features like logging and reporting results (through e-mail or otherwise); excluding system and directories; and allowing people to customize the list of files/directories.

Thanks for all the help!

**UPDATE**

Before I incorporated the helpful suggestions provided by everyone, I performed some tests, the results of which were very interesting (see below).

As a test, I ran this command:

```
root@doi:~# find /media/disk3 -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

The results (which is what I expected):

```
rm -rf /media/disk3/Videos/Chorus/.AppleDouble
```

**However**, when I ran the actual command (without `echo`):

```
root@doi:~# find /media/disk3 -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I received the same "error" output:

```
find: `/media/disk3/Videos/Chorus/.AppleDouble': No such file or directory
```

I put "error" in quotes because obviously the folder was removed, as verified by immediately running:

```
root@doi:~# find /media/disk3 -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf {} \;
root@doi:~#
```

It seems like the `find` command stored the original results, acted on it by deleting the directory, but then tried to delete it again?  Or is the `-f` option of `rm`, which is supposed to be for ignoring nonexistent files and arguments, is ignored?  I note that when I run tests with the `rm` command alone without the `find` command, everything worked as expected.  Thus, directly running `rm -rf ... \nonexistent_directory`, no errors were returned even though the "non_existent_directory" was not there, and directly running `rm -r \nonexistent_directory` provided the expected:

```
rm: cannot remove 'non_existent_directory': No such file or directory
```

Should I use the `-delete` option instead of the `-exec rm ...` option?  I had wanted to make the script as broadly applicable as possible for systems that didn't have `-delete` option for `find`.

Lastly, I don't presume it matters if `/media/disk1`, `/media/disk2`, ... are combined in an AUFS filesystem under `/media/storage` as the `find` command is operating on the individual disks themselves?
Thanks for all the help so far, guys.  I'll publish the script when I'm done.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm writing a bash script to delete a few OS X remnants on my Lubuntu file shares.  However, when executing this:

```
...
BASE_DIR="/media/disk" # I have 4 disks: disk1, disk2, ...   
COUNTER=1

while [ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]; do      # Iterate through disk1, disk2, ...
   DIRTY_DIR=${BASE_DIR}$COUNTER     # Look under the current disk counter /media/disk1, /media/disk2, ...
   find $DIRTY_DIR -name \.AppleDouble -exec rm -rf {} \;    # Delete all .AppleDouble directories
   find $DIRTY_DIR -name ".*DS_Store" -exec rm -rf {} \;     # Delete all .DS_Store and ._.DS_Store files
   COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1))
done
...
```

I see the following output:

find: `/media/disk1/Pictures/.AppleDouble`: No such file or directory

Before I added the `-exec rm ...` portion the script found the `/media/disk1/Pictures/.AppleDouble` directory. The script works properly for removing DS_Store files, but what am I missing for the find command for directories?

I'm afraid to screw too much with the `-exec` portion as I don't want to obliterate directories in error.

Comment: You should probably have a `-type d` flag on the first [tag:find] and a `-type f` flag on the second (also don't need `r` on the `rm` for the second). So it doesn't delete files that are named similar to directories and vice versa, and so it doesn't needlessly descend.

Comment: Try debugging with `-exec echo rm -rf {} \;`. I would add `-depth` to ensure ./a/b/X/c/X is deleted before ./a/b/X

Comment: @BroSlow Thanks for catching those. I know I should be a little more careful and have added it to my script.

Comment: @glenn In this case, would it be bad if ./a/b/X was deleted as I don't want to keep anything under .AppleDouble anyway?

Comment: What you experience is probably that when you don't use `-delete`, you don't have the implied `-depth` option; so you end up deleting files which have been already deleted by previous iterations of your find command. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170999/ for more information.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/delete-files-and-directories-by-their-names-no-such-file-or-directory/115869#115869

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape DOT in shell glob as this is not regex. So use `.AppleDouble` instead of `\.AppleDouble`:

```
find $DIRTY_DIR -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

**PS:** I don't see anywhere `$COUNTER` being incremented in your script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put it in the "edited" version of the script.  It was actually in there, I just forgot to keep it in when I was deleting the "irrelevant parts of the script.

Comment: Ok I see edited question now. Can you try: `find /media/disk3 -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf '{}' \; -prune` command?

Comment: So it turned out to be a combination of things--see what I did above.

Answer (score 57):

**tl;dr - Pass `-prune` if you're deleting directories using `find`.**

For anyone else who stumbles on this question. Running an example like this

```
find /media/disk3 -type d -name .AppleDouble -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

results in an error like

```
rm: cannot remove 'non_existent_directory': No such file or directory
```

When finding and deleting directories with find, you'll often encounter this error because `find` stores the directory to process subdirectories, then deletes it with `exec`, then tries to traverse the subdirectories which no longer exist.

You can either pass `-maxdepth 0` or `-prune` to prevent this issue. Like so:

```
find /media/disk3 -type d -name .AppleDouble -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Now it deletes the directories without any errors. Hurray! :)